# nestjs + socket.io serving websockets from microservice at nested path instead of the root of the host always returns 404 Not Found

Tags: websocket, socket.io, nestjs, nestjs-gateways

I'm using the socket.io implementation with nestjs. My overall in-production architecture is relying on a load balancer to route requests on paths to microservice containers.

One of them contains a websocket that interacts with user data and is nested on `mydomain.com/apis/user`

On my gateway I've configured it to use this path:

```
@WebSocketGateway({ path: "/apis/user/gateway", namespace: "/apis/user/gateway" })
```

and I've tried variations without the namespace there and with just the path.

I also have a global prefix:   `app.setGlobalPrefix("apis/user");` removing this makes no difference, it seems I need to define the path to the gateway either way prefix or not.

Then on the client I'm trying to just connect to it via either adding the path in the url, or to the options object, as such:

```
    const endpoint = "https://example.com/apis/user/gateway";

    socket = io(endpoint, {
      secure: true,
      path: "/apis/user/gateway",
    });
```

This works for the path and handleConnection triggers on the gateway nested there, however configuring polling on the backend does not work, the client still throws:

```
 https://example.com/apis/user/gateway/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NXVpMfB 404 Not Found
```

Comment: I have same problem. Only the default config at the root / works :(

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, all the various options are confusing. I got it sorted though, here is what worked:

For the nestjs:

```
@WebSocketGateway({
  cors: {
    origin: '*',
  },
  namespace: '/api/v1/ws',
  path: '/api/v1/ws/socket.io',
})
```

For socket.io:

```
const newSocket = io("http://localhost:3000/api/v1/ws", {
      path: "/api/v1/ws/socket.io",
    });
```